# Как убрать диск с FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: freebsd

Есть несколько дисков. Как безболезненно убрать `ad0`, чтобы система продолжала нормально грузится с `ada2`?

```
# gpart show
=> 34 390721901 ada0 GPT (186G)
34 390721901 1 freebsd-ufs (186G)

=> 34 390721901 ufsid/554a9b5efc8c7a5e GPT (186G)
34 390721901 1 freebsd-ufs (186G)

=> 34 390721901 diskid/DISK-4LJ13VAN GPT (186G)
34 390721901 1 freebsd-ufs (186G)

=> 34 156301421 ada1 GPT (75G)
34 156301421 1 freebsd-ufs (75G)

=> 34 625142381 ada2 GPT (298G)
34 128 1 freebsd-boot (64K)
162 616562560 2 freebsd-ufs (294G)
616562722 8388608 3 freebsd-swap (4.0G)
624951330 191085 - free - (93M)

=> 63 312581745 ada3 MBR (149G)
63 312576642 1 ntfs (149G)
312576705 5103 - free - (2.5M)

=> 63 312581745 diskid/DISK-5SV0BK2P MBR (149G)
63 312576642 1 ntfs (149G)
312576705 5103 - free - (2.5M)
```

Comment: [FAQ пункт 8.2, подпункт 4](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/faq/disks.html). Есть еще программа [sade](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sade&sektion=8) для редактирования разделов на диске с удобным псевдографическим интерфейсом.

Comment: что значит "убрать"? убрать что бы система его вообще не видела как устройство? зайти в BIOS и отключить, там же можно поменять приоритет загрузки

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто убрать. И убедиться что в /etc/fstab нет разделов с ada0, автоматически монтирующихся при старте системы.